# LogPlot axes labels destroyed when working in high precision

Tags: plotting, bugs, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

(I'm using *Mathematica* 8.)

I have a Taylor series:

```
poly = Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

I want to produce a log-linear plot of the error. This is easy enough with the following code:

```
LogPlot[Abs[E^x - poly], {x, -1, 1}]
```

This produces

[image: a log-linear plot]

Now, I want to plot even smaller values of the error (in particular I want the plot to be sensible near zero), so I tell `LogPlot` to use high precision as follows:

```
LogPlot[Abs[E^x - poly], {x, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

However this destroys the labeling on the y-axis:

[image: bad behavior of LogPlot[]]

Does anyone know what has gone wrong here? How do I fix it?

Comment: No solution, just some comments: `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` will use machine precision (default).  `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` will *not* use machine precision, but the built-in arbitrary precision with the same number of digits as machine precision.  For high precision you would *not* want `MachinePrecision`, but set a higher number in `WorkingPrecision` (which as you noticed produces a plot with a wrong scale).

Comment: Setting `WorkingPrecision`, as in your example, crashes version 9.  Can anyone reproduce this in 9?

Comment: @Szabolcs For me it doesn't crash a session but it yields a plot of a constant function, so it is incorrect.

Comment: I had read "$MachinePrecision denotes arbitrary precision numbers with the same precision as machine reals, but crucially, with precision tracking switched on. This allows `Plot` to adaptively increase the working precision (by up to `$MaxExtraPrecision` base-10 digits) in order to produce an accurate plot, whereas without precision tracking it has no way to know when numerical errors become significant." ... Anyway to avoid confusion I've just set the `WorkingPrecision` to 30 in the question.

Comment: @aukie thought that quotation looked familiar. :) [source](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Dec/msg00459.html)

Comment: @OleksandrR. Small World!

Comment: @Szabolcs it crashes the kernel on macosX 10.7.5 +mma 9.0

Comment: I'm tagging as bug, as this is more than an axis-labelling issue. I'm pretty sure there was a question where this came up before, but I can't find it unfortunately.

Comment: Apparently this bug still exists in MMA 9.0.1...Can't believe such a bug happens and remains unsolved for quite a long time.

Comment: @Szabolcs do you know what is the status of this bug in 10.3.1?  Thanks!

Comment: @QuantumDot Broken.

Comment: @Szabolcs Seriously? This bug persists in v11?? Given how important it is to produce high precision log-plots in scientific disciplines, I find this abhorrent.

Comment: @QuantumDot No, it's **fixed** in v11.  It's one of the big fixes I'm glad about.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh; I misread!  What do you expect would happen after reading all your edits with "...and persists in 11.0"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not simply a mislabeling of the axes.  More than that is going on: the plot produced is not even logarithmic.  Let's try to use the default (non-log-transformed tick marks):

First, with `MachinePrecision` (correct result):

```
Show[
 LogPlot[Abs[E^x - poly], {x, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision],
 Ticks -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then with higher precision (incorrect result):

```
Show[
 LogPlot[Abs[E^x - poly], {x, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30],
 Ticks -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't think it's worth digging into how `LogPlot` works, as at this point this clearly seems to be a bug.

---

You can work around it by using `Plot` instead of `LogPlot`:

```
Plot[Log@Abs[E^x - poly], {x, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But then you have to do re-label the axes yourself (CustomTicks / LevelScheme are helpful packages).  If you don't mind losing adaptive plotting, you can generate the points to be shown yourself and us `ListLogPlot`:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[Evaluate@Abs[E^x - poly], {x, -1, 1, 0.01`30}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(You'd probably want `Joined -> True` here, but seeing where the points are helps you tune the plot, so I didn't include it now.)

Comment: Thanks If you could show how to use `Plot` with the `CustomTicks` package, that would be very useful

Comment: Better yet: have `Plot[]` take care of the adaptive sampling, and pass the points thus generated to `ListLogPlot[]`.

Answer (score 9):

Although Szabolcs warned *"I don't think it's worth digging into how LogPlot works, as at this point this clearly seems to be a bug"* I thought I would give a go.  I found that:

`` System`LogPlot `` calls `` Graphics`LogPlotDump`scaledPlot `` which calls `` System`Plot `` which calls `` System`ProtoPlotDump`iPlot `` which calls `` Visualization`Core`Plot `` which is not readable.

We can demonstrate that the problem exists in this innermost function by making direct use of `"MappingFunctions"` which is what `LogPlot` ultimately becomes (among a few other settings):

```
poly = Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 10}]];

Table[
 Visualization`Core`Plot[Abs[E^x - poly], {x, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
  Method -> {"MappingFunctions" -> {{#1, Log[#2]} &, {#1, #2} &}}],
 {wp, {MachinePrecision, 30}}
]
```

[image]

This bug therefore appears to be beyond our reach to fix. :-(

Answer (score 7):

neat little work-around,

```
poly[x_] = Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 10}]];
LogPlot[(Abs[E^# - poly[#]] &@N[Rationalize[x, 0], 20]), {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Problem persists with Mathematica version "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)"

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER but rather an extended comment providing an update for Mma v10.1.

In looking at the issue referenced in [LogPlot does not show all points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87700/logplot-does-not-show-all-points), I noticed that use of `WorkingPrecision` causes really odd results on my system (Mac OS 10.10.4) with Mathematica 10.1. A related issue with `LogLogPlot` and version 10 is documented in [WorkingPrecision in LogLogPlot creates wrong plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75340/workingprecision-in-loglogplot-creates-wrong-plots).

This problem appears to have gotten worse since the frame ticks and labels are not displayed at all--although they appear in a saved file using `Save Selection As...`

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
LogPlot[1/x, {x, 10^-12, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, All}, Frame -> True, 
 WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]
```

AS DISPLAYED:

[image]

AS SAVED using `Save Selection As...`:

[image]