# Plotting a defined function gives different results from plotting the function directly

Tags: plotting, function-construction, bugs

Consider the following piece of code:

```
function[t_]:=Exp[-9 t^2];
LogLogPlot[{function[t],Exp[-9 t^2]},{t,.01,100}]
```

I expect the two plots to exactly overlap each other. However this is not the case and my result looks something like this:

[image: Result of LogLogPlot]

Clearly using the direct expression is correct as the exponential tends to 0 for very large and negative arguments. Why is there a difference between plotting the defined function and plotting the expression directly? Is this a bug?

Comment: I think `HoldAll` together with the veeeery small numbers is causing this, thus: `LogLogPlot[Evaluate@{function[t], Exp[-t^2]}, {t, .01, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> All]` works. I am afraid I cannot offer any better explanation at the moment.

Comment: @Pinguin But unfortunately `{LogLogPlot[function[t],{t, .01, 100}], LogLogPlot[Exp[-t^2], {t, .01, 100}]}` gives different results. Of course the difference is almost infinitesimal, but I don't expect such difference. Furthermore, if `g = Exp[-9 #^2] &` is used, `LogLogPlot[g@t, {t, .01, 100}]` also displays correctly. And `LogLogPlot` does not seem to react to different vertical plot ranges...

Comment: If this helps at all, it indeed does seem like the extremely small numbers have something to do with this. For example, if I change the argument from -9 t^2 to say -5 t^2, then the 'step' in the defined function appears at a large value of time. So the jump appears to happen when the value that is to be plotted hits a particular value.

Comment: I suspect this somehow has to do with the bug appearing in `LogPlot` (for example see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/logplot-axes-labels-destroyed-when-working-in-high-precision)) but can't come up a way to analyze it. A workaround for your problem is `LogLogPlot[{function[t],Exp[-9 t^2]}, {t,.01,100}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem arises when `function` returns a number smaller than `$MinMachineNumber`:

```
function[t_] := Exp[-9 t^2];
LogLogPlot[function[t], {t, 8.8718, 8.872}, PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> {{{Sqrt[Log[1/$MinMachineNumber]]/3, 
     Directive[Thick, Dashed]}}, None}]
Show[%, Ticks -> Automatic]
```

[image: screenshot]

For some reason `LogLogPlot` considers numbers smaller than `$MinMachineNumber` as having logarithm equal to `0`, which is incorrect of course.

The workaround suggested in the comments is to abandon machine numbers by switching to arbitrary precision arithmetics. Even if one sets `WorkingPrecision` much smaller than `$MachinePrecision` this bug completely disappears, **but now [another bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15642/280) arises**: the plot produced is not logarithmic in vertical scale and has incorrect vertical tick labels:

```
LogLogPlot[{function[t], Exp[-9 t^2]}, {t, .01, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 3]
```

[image: screenshot]

It is easy to see that the line computed with non-`MachinePrecision` `WorkingPrecision` is identical to the one generated by `LogLinearPlot`:

```
LogLogPlot[t^3, {t, 1/100, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 3][[1]] === 
 LogLinearPlot[t^3, {t, 1/100, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 3][[1]]
```

> True

---

Note that numbers which cannot be expressed as machine numbers are not affected when one tries to convert them to machine numbers:

```
SetPrecision[function[8.872], MachinePrecision] // Precision
```

> 12.9256

So another workaround would be to perform conversion of non-machine-size real numbers manually:

```
function[t_?NumberQ] := 
 If[$MinMachineNumber < Exp[-9 t^2] < $MaxMachineNumber, Exp[-9 t^2], 
  Indeterminate]
```

Now `LogLogPlot` behaves as expected.

Even better way is to switch off generation of non-machine numbers:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]
```

This way completely removes discussed bug and does not introduce new bugs but it is strongly advisable to localize the effect of this setting as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25668/280).

Another workaround is [suggested by halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37737/280).

---

And of course it is possible to switch to another function which has no bugs. In this case `LogLinearPlot`  adaptive plotting capabilities can be utilized:

```
function[t_?NumberQ] := Exp[-9 t^2]
points = Reap[
   LogLinearPlot[
    Log@Last@Sow[{t, {function[t], Exp[-9 t^2]}}], {t, .01, 100}]][[2,
    1]]
ListLogLogPlot[Sort /@ Transpose[Thread /@ points], Joined -> True]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You put your finger on it: ``LogLogPlot[{function[t], Exp[-9 t^2]}, {t, .01`20, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`` works (i.e., abandon machine numbers).

Comment: Just noticed @LeoFang commented on `WorkingPrecision` already. Note though that `WorkingPrecision -> 3` still produces a pretty good graph.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, the trick with `WorkingPrecision` works. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Michael I just checked it again and notice that `WorkingPrecision` actually introduces another bug: look at the vertical axis! When `t` goes to `0` the function must go to `1` but after setting `WorkingPrecision` we get value greater than `2`!

Comment: How very odd! It seems to not plot `Log` of the function when `WorkingPrecision` is not `MachinePrecision`. Even for `LogLogPlot[t^3, {t, 1/100, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 3]`.

Comment: @Michael You are right: `LogLogPlot[t^3, {t, 1/100, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 3][[1]] === 
 LogLinearPlot[t^3, {t, 1/100, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 3][[1]]` returns `True`.

Answer (score 10):

When tracing other plots, I often saw that plotting-related functions compile their arguments when possible. A quick look at the trace of your example suggests the same, because the `Exp` function is used only for the evaluation of `function`. This seems to indicate that your second argument `Exp[-9 t^2]` was already compiled down and doesn't show up when the numeric values for the plot are generated.

To support my hypothesis, let us change your example to create a plot that matches completely by compiling `function` down:

```
With[{cf = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, Exp[-9 t^2]]},
 functionC[t_?NumericQ] := cf[t]
];

LogLogPlot[{functionC[t], Exp[-9 t^2]}, {t, .01, 100}]
```

Because `LogLogPlot` tries to analyze `functionC`, I wrapped the compiled function with `?NumericQ`. The result shows two matching graphs:

[image]

If you now want to gain further inside, you can concentrate on the difference between the compiled function and the evaluatation of `Exp[-9 t^2]`.