# CompiledFunction returns machine numbers smaller than $MinMachineNumber

Tags: numerics, compile, machine-precision

When thinking on the workaround for [this `LogLogPlot` bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37761/280) [suggested by halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37737/280) I noticed that `CompiledFunction` actually can return machine numbers smaller than `$MinMachineNumber`. Consider:

```
f = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, Exp[-9 t^2]];
num = f[8.872]
num < $MinMachineNumber
MachineNumberQ[num]
MachineNumberQ[num2 = ToExpression[ToString[num, StandardForm]]]
```

> 2.191864698767832`*^-308
>
> True
>
> True
>
> False

As you see, `num` is smaller than `$MinMachineNumber` BUT `MachineNumberQ` returns `True`. Conversion of this number into `String` and backward returns arbitrary-precision number.

Moreover, `CompiledFunction` accepts such numbers and works with them correctly:

```
f2 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sqrt@x];
f2[num]
```

> 1.480494747970364`*^-154

How this behavior could be explained? Does it mean that `CompiledFunction` actually CAN work with arbitrary-precision numbers?

P.S. I use *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Congratulations! You find one of [subnormal positive double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) :)

Another example

```
f = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 2.0^t];

f[-1074]
f[-1075]
```

> ```
> 5.*10^-324
> 0
> ```

```
MachineNumberQ@f[-1074]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This doesn't mean that `CompiledFunction` can work with arbitrary-precision numbers.

**Update**

Normally *Mathematica* prevents such numbers

```
2.^-1074.
% // MachineNumberQ
```

> ```
> 4.940656458413*10^-324
> False
> ```

But after a "hack" we can create subnormal positive double manually

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False];
2.^-1074.
% // MachineNumberQ
```

> ```
> 5.*10^-324
> True
> ```

See also [Improving speed of Exp[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24857/4678).

Note that *Mathematica* displays only the first digit of this number (a little bug). All digits:

```
RealDigits[%%]
```

> ```
> {{4, 9, 4, 0, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 8, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5}, -323}
> ```

Comment: Good old floating-point magic :)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, they are machine numbers (they satisfy IEEE 754 double-precision standard). Therefore, `MachineNumberQ` returns `True`.

Comment: How can I enter a subnormal positive double by hands? Entering `5.*^-324` gives arbitrary-precision number.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It doesn't fit in the comment so I post it in the update of my answer.

Comment: Subnormals are normally handled (slowly) by microcode or in software rather than by the floating-point unit directly. I wonder, is there any way to switch on flush-to-zero?

Comment: `first digit of this number (a little bug)` it's not a bug — it's reflection of the fact that there's that much precision in this representation (next representable value is `1e-323`). `libdouble-conversion` as well as `gdtoa` will also give you a single decimal digit for `2^-1074` when asked to format in "shortest" form compatible with binary-decimal-binary round-trip criterion.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @ybeltukov's excellent answer, I thought it would be worth noting the behaviour of [RuntimeOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html), when compiling to either the Wolfram Virtual Machine (WVM) or to C, for these [subnormal positive doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

```
f = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, Exp[-9 t^2]];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
f[1.]    (* = 0.00012341 *)
f[8.872] (* = 2.191*10^-308 *)

Do[f[1.], {i, 10000}] // AccurateTiming
(* 0.0066 seconds *)

Do[f[8.872], {i, 10000}] // AccurateTiming
(* 0.0652 seconds *)
```

The difference in timings is an interesting one because of the subnormal result of  `f[8.872]` - take a look at this plot to see.

```
range = {6., 7., 8., 8.871, 8.872, 9., 10., 11., 12.};
times = AccurateTiming[Do[f[#], {i, 10000}]] & /@ range;
ListPlot[Transpose[{range,times}]]
```

[image]

The default for `"RuntimeOptions"` is to not catch machine underflow. This can be turned on e.g.

```
f2 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, Exp[-9 t^2],
                RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True}];
f2[1.]    (* all fine as before *)
f2[8.872] (* uh-oh! CompiledFunction::cfne *)
```

> CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

This error has an associated performance hit, as it jumps out to uncompiled evaluation.

```
Do[f2[1.], {i, 10000}] // AccurateTiming
(* 0.0063 seconds *)

Do[f2[8.872], {i, 10000}] // AccurateTiming
(* 0.3324 seconds *)
```

Now look at the timing performance when the underflow is caught. Again, the sub-normal `f2[8.872]` is a tricky one to handle compared to subsequent results.

[image]