# How do I convert an inexact number smaller than $MinMachineNumber to machine-precision?

Tags: conversion, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I was trying to convert some arbitrary-precision numbers to machine-precision numbers using `N[myNumber,MachinePrecision]`. But, although my test number did lose some precision, it still had a very strange exponent:

```
number = 5.803736411761291186334053015446685`16*^-400;
number1 = SetPrecision[number, MachinePrecision]
```

> 5.803736411761291×10^-400

As $10^{-400}$ is not representable in IEEE 754 `binary64`, and I'm on x86 where this format is native, I tried checking what precision the number has, and it appears

```
Precision@number1
```

> 15.954589770191

This might be OK if truly machine-precision numbers gave the same, but they don't:

```
Precision@1.5
```

> MachinePrecision

Finally, I've checked my number given by `SetPrecision` using `FullForm`:

```
FullForm@number1
```

> 5.803736411761291186334053015446685`15.954589770191005*^-400

So, apparently, `SetPrecision` won't give me machine number. How then do I convert my arbitrary-precision number to machine number? (I'd expect the $~10^{-400}$ value to be rounded down to machine zero.)

Comment: `N[number]`?? From Documentation Center page "MachinePrecision": "MachinePrecision is the symbol representing the number of decimal digits used by numerical functions such as N, NIntegrate, and NSum in the Wolfram Language for machine-precision computations."

Comment: @murray have you actually tried it? Its result is not different from that from `SetPrecision[number,MachinePrecision]`.

Comment: Related: [(37764)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37764/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This situation is comparable to

```
$MinMachineNumber / 2
```

automatically giving an arbitrary precision result.

```
Precision[$MinMachineNumber/2]
(* 15.9546 *)
```

Mathematica detects the underflow condition and switches to arbitrary precision arithmetic.  This can be turned off:

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]
```

Now the result of `$MinMachineNumber/2` has `MachinePrecision`.  The result is not `0.`, but a [denormal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), I believe (my knowledge is lacking in this area).  If you divide by a number larger than `10^$MachinePrecision` then you get a `0.`.

```
$MinMachineNumber/2
(* 1.11254*10^-308 *)

$MinMachineNumber/10^15
(* 2.5*10^-323 *)

$MinMachineNumber/10^16
(* 0. *)
```

`SetPrecision` works as you want it, too.

```
number = 5.803736411761291186334053015446685`16*^-400;
number1 = SetPrecision[number, MachinePrecision]
(* 0. *)
```

`SetPrecision` will not create denormal numbers, it seems.

```
SetPrecision[1.2`16*^-308, MachinePrecision]
(* 0. *)
```

Comment: With V11.1.1 running on OS X 10.10.2, I do not get the OP's result from `SetPrecision`, not yours.

Comment: Wow never supposed Mathematica would use allow denormals (they are performance killers for machine-precision computations). Is there any way to enable [Flush-To-Zero mode](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/x87-and-sse-floating-point-assists-in-ia-32-flush-to-zero-ftz-and-denormals-are-zero-daz) in Mathematica (other than attaching a debugger and change `MXCSR` manually :) )?

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry, I do not understand. What do you get precisely when underflow checking is enabled/disabled?

Comment: I did not read your post carefully enough to realize the results you showed applied to the case where catching machine overflow had been turned off.

Answer (score 7):

```
number = 5.803736411761291186334053015446685`16*^-400;
number + 0.
(* 0. *)
```

`N` makes arbitrary precision numbers when either given a second argument or a number not representable by a machine number as its first argument. However, machine numbers in expressions generally coerce arithmetic into the machine domain.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
toMPReal = Compile[x, x][#] &(*/.c_Compile :> RuleCondition[c]*);

toMPReal[5.803736411761291186334053015446685`16*^-400]
(*  0.  *)
```

Uncomment the replacement rule to pre-compile the function.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in M11.3, [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision) will always produce a machine number when the second argument is [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision). The documentation for [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision) was unfortunately not updated with this change. Also, this means that the system option `SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> True]` no longer does anything. So, now you get the desired behavior without modifying any system options:

```
number = 5.803736411761291186334053015446685`16*^-400;
number1 = SetPrecision[number,MachinePrecision]
```

> 0.