# How can I suppress the warning "precision may be lost"?

Tags: import, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

When I import [data](https://pastebin.com/gkB6zKVC) from a `.dat` file, V11.3 emits the message: *is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost*.

How can I close the display or replace the offending number with 0.?

Here is my code:

```
ReadList[OpenRead["C:\\Users\\px\\Desktop\\1.DAT"], Real]
```

I know `Import` will not show this warning, but its speed is slow.

Comment: You can use `Quiet[]` of course, but this just hides problems. Can you post a sample `.dat` file that is triggering this warning?

Comment: Except for you, no one else has the file `1.DAT`. How do you expect to get help if you don't post that file?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, I  don't ’how to upload attachments

Comment: Copy the contents of `1.DAT`, go to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), post the contents there, and then post a link here.

Comment: @ J. M. is slightly pensive Thanks JM. `https://pastebin.com/gkB6zKVC` Is this link ok?

Comment: `$MinMachineNumber` is `2.22507*10^-308` (Windows 10, *Mathematica* 10.4).  Your dataset has 9 out of 15580 numbers between `1.094829709000000*10^-318`and `1.319006165000000*10^-316`.  If it is appropriate you could modify the data or maybe the following would be helpful:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161031/how-do-i-convert-an-inexact-number-smaller-than-minmachinenumber-to-machine-pre.

Comment: Thanks `Quiet[]` is enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

If we multiply the exponents by, say, `10^20`, then the data will fall within machine-precision range.  There may be a more natural way to rescale (based on units, for instance), but we have only raw numbers to work with.  (One can also convert the mantissas to arbitrary-precision number before multiplying by the exponent; however, I suspect that machine numbers are to be preferred.)

```
data = #1*10.^(#2 + 20) & @@ Transpose[
     ToExpression[
      StringSplit[#, "E"] & /@
       (raw = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/gkB6zKVC", "Table", "Numeric" -> False])
      ],
     {2, 3, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.216465, Null}  *)
```

Some checks.  There are some rounding differences between the imported data and the converted data.

```
Dimensions@data
Dimensions@raw
(*
  {76, 205}
  {76, 205}
*)

Quiet@Block[{Indeterminate = 0},
  Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/gkB6zKVC", "Table"]/data // 
    Flatten // DeleteDuplicates
  ]
(*
{0, 1.0000000000000001`*^-20, 1.0000000000000002`*^-20, 
    9.999999999999998`*^-21,  9.999999996284607`*^-21, 
    9.99999999915014`*^-21,   1.0000000000496418`*^-20, 
    1.0000000001289331`*^-20, 1.0000000002912905`*^-20, 
    1.000000000045069`*^-20,  9.999999995966217`*^-21, 
    1.0000000002256684`*^-20, 9.99999999965454`*^-21} 
*)
```