# Specifying WorkingPrecision in LogLogPlot produces invalid plots

Tags: plotting, bugs, precision-and-accuracy, logarithmic-scale

I seem to have found a bug with `LogLogPlot` in Version 10. If I specify a working precision, the function produces total garbage. Here is a simple example. The first case, without `WorkingPrecision` specified works fine. The second case, with `WorkingPrecision` specified, produces garbage.

```
LogLogPlot[{1/10, 1, 2, 3}, {p, 0.1, 10000}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
LogLogPlot[{1/10, 1, 2, 3}, {p, 0.1, 10000}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", WorkingPrecision -> 16]
```

[image]

If `WorkingPrecision` is not a specifiable option for `LogLogPlot`, why doesn't *Mathematica* warn me? I know it's OK to specify `WorkingPrecision` for normal plots. Any ideas?

Comment: confirmed (v9).  The plot itself seems to become linear, and the axis labels garbage.

Comment: Confirmed 10.0.2.0, even without the `PlotLegends->"Expressions"` option.

Comment: I don't know if this has been reported as a bug to Wolfram yet, but I can confirm the same behavior in v9.0 and v10.0 (Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

With `LogLogPlot[..., WorkingPrecision->_]` (or indeed `LogPlot[..., WorkingPrecision->_]`), what is plotted is in fact the exponential of the function. As a workaround (assuming that's what you're looking for), you can use

```
LogLogPlot[Evaluate@Log[{1/10, 1, 2, 3}], {p, 0.1, 10000}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", WorkingPrecision -> 16]
```

which produces something very similar to your first figure (but this legend is incorrect, of course).