# LogPlot does not show all points

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

`LogPlot` ignores points which are going to "too high" values:

```
LogPlot[1/x, {x, 10^-12, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, All},Frame -> True]
```

gives:

[image]

I'd rather expect to see:

[image]

which was done by use of

```
ListLogPlot[{#, 1/#} & /@ Range[10^-12, 1, .001],
            PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, All}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

How to force `LogPlot` to see `ALL` points, especially those at the boundary
of arguments?

Comment: You can try `PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, {0, 10^12}}` or so.

Comment: The problem is not caused by an improper `PlotRange` or ignoring "points which are going to "too high" ". The reason why there are no higher values shown is that the first x-value at which the function `1/x` is evaluated is `Cases[LogPlot[1/x, {x, 10^-12, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, All}, 
  Frame -> True], Line[x_] :> x[[1, 1]], Infinity]` => `{2.04092*10^-8}`.

Comment: Increasing the number of `PlotPoints` helps, but doesn't solve the problem completely.

Comment: @b.gatessucks  - it does not work, or even worse, I checked it before posting

Comment: @Karsten 7 - that I also have been trying,  even with PlotPoints->100 000, I still cant get the proper value at the peak.

Comment: LogPlot still makes trouble, the same was in previous versions. It makes an arbitary  "clipping" of the argument range.

Comment: That "clipping" seems to be a general "feature" of the `Plot` functions and the result of how the initial sample points are generated.

Comment: One could put all three answers together and define `myLogPlot[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[ListLogPlot]] := 
 ListLogPlot[
  Cases[Plot[f, {x} \[Element] Line[{{xmin}, {xmax}}], 
    PlotRange -> All], Line[points__] :> points, Infinity], opts, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]`.

Answer (score 9):

The fact that your plot doesn't show "too high" values isn't specific to `LogPlot`, has nothing to do with the `PlotRange` you specified, and also isn't due to the values being "too high". It is the result of the initial sampling of the plot points. According to my observations so far, no `Plot` includes the lower and upper limit specified for the variable. For example `Plot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}` plots f for `xmin < x < xmax` and not for `xmin <= x <= xmax`, meaning f is plotted for the open interval $(xmin, xmax)$ and not for  $[xmin, xmax]$.

First, one way to make your `LogPlot` look like your `ListLogPlot`

```
LogPlot[1/x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, All}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotPoints -> 1000001, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.05]}}]
```

[image: LogPlot]

Using `{x, 0, 1}` together with `PlotPoints -> 1000001` makes the plot start at `1.*10^-12` and end at `1 - 1.*10^-12`. The `PlotRangePadding` is only added for an easier visual comparison, as the default is different for `LogPlot` and `ListLogPlot`.

Using such a high number of `PlotPoints` makes generating the plot much slower than using your `ListLogPlot`, which seems to be the better choice for this situation.

---

### The problem generalized

Even a very simple plot like

```
Plot[1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> [image]

does not start at `x == 0` and end at `x == 1`, it starts at `x == 2.040816326530612*^-8` and ends at `x == 0.999999979591837`. The only difference is, that here it isn't as obvious as in your `1/x` case.
It is also worth pointing out, that this is not limited to the case where `xmin` is `0`.

### How to observe what is going on.

There is an extensive [How does Plot work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29346/how-does-plot-work) Q&A that already analyses the inner workings of `Plot`. However, the problem that the function isn't plotted for `xmin` and `xmax` isn't part of it.

Let's first define a function that will print out its input and evaluate to 1

```
probe[x_] := (Print[NumberForm[x, Infinity]]; 1)
```

Using this function inside plot and extracting all the x values plotted

```
Cases[Plot[probe[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 11, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PlotRange -> All], Line[x_] :> NumberForm[x[[All, 1]], Infinity], Infinity] // Flatten
```

> [image: Out]

shows, that the function `probe` is first evaluated for `xmin == -1`, than for an x value slightly bigger, than `probe` is evaluated symbolically (could be suppresses by defining `probe` only for numerical values) and finally `probe` is evaluated at the 11 plot points starting with a value between the first two evaluations.

Answer (score 3):

`Plot` does not use open sampling on regions, so with the following we get the whole range:

```
Plot[1/x, {x} ∈ Line[{{10^-12}, {1}}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

Unfortunately, there's a bug in `LogPlot`:

```
LogPlot[1/x, {x} ∈ Line[{{10^-12}, {1}}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, All}, Frame -> True]
(*  Graphics`LogPlotDump`scaledPlot[]  *)
```

So here's a workaround using `Plot` to mimic  `LogPlot`.

```
ClearAll[logPlot];
SetAttributes[logPlot, HoldAll];
logPlot[f_, stuff__] := Plot[Log[f], stuff,
   Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]},
   FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
      Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
   CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> ({#1[[1]], Exp[#1[[2]]]} &), 
     "CopiedValueFunction" -> ({#1[[1]], Exp[#1[[2]]]} &)}];

logPlot[1/x, {x} ∈ Line[{{10^-12}, {1}}],
 PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1}, All}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note using the alternative form `Method -> {ScalingFunctions -> {Log, Exp}}` in `Plot` also crashes the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the explanation.

I think it is  a bad philosophy of Plot. I may understand that it uses open interval but when I use option PlotRange->All I expect to see ALL points
on the CLOSED interval. I had interpolated functions and wanted to see
their behaviour on the boundary and the Plot[] was annoyingly misleading. 
Finally I defined my own LogPlot[] based on ListLogPlot[]:

```
MyLogPlot[fun_, range_, opts___] := 
  Module[{var = range[[1]], xmin = range[[2]], xmax = range[[3]],
    nn = PlotPoints /. Join[{opts}, {PlotPoints -> 30}], pts, optsi}, 
    pts = Function[Evaluate[var, {var, fun}]] /@ 
    Range[xmin, xmax, 1. (xmax - xmin)/nn];
    optsi = DeleteCases[{opts}, PlotPoints -> _];
  ListLogPlot[pts, optsi, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]]
```

the additional benefit is that it warns me when I plot interpolated function and exceed the interpolation domain. This is ignored by Plot[] which is again highly annoying, as it makes arbitrary extrapolation for interpolated function.

Comment: Just a side note: you can shorten `var = range[[1]], xmin = range[[2]], xmax = range[[3]]` in `{var, xmin, xmax} = range`

Comment: @Peltio better still use `MyLogPlot[fun_, {var_, xmim_, xmax_}, opts___] := . . .`

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a practical workaround.

Plot the function as you would like with defined PlotPoints and PlotRange. FullForm shows you how to extract the first x-value x0. Plot the graph a second time and try with Manipulate how much starting value for x has to be varied.

```
lp = LogPlot[1/x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotRange -> {{10^-12, 1}, All}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> .1, Frame -> True]

lp // FullForm;

x0 = First@Cases[lp, Line[{{uu_, _}, __}] -> uu, 4]

SetOptions[Manipulator, Appearance -> "Labeled"];

Manipulate[
 LogPlot[1/x, {x, -x0 + z, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotRange -> {{10^-12, 1}, All}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .1, Frame -> True], 
 {z, -2 10^-12, 2 10^-12}]
```

[image]