# Unexpected function evaluation result in Plot

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I find some strange behaviors of Plot. The code is:

```
f[x_] := (Print[x]; x);
Plot[f[a], {a, 1, 3}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 2, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{a, f[a]}]]
```

And I get the output:

```
1
a
1.002
1.
1.
{1.,1.}
3.
3.
{3.,3.}
```

I understand that

```
1.
1.
{1.,1.}
3.
3.
{3.,3.}
```

are normal outputs as expected. But what are

```
1
a
1.002
```

before that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [How does Plot work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29346/how-does-plot-work)

Comment: Also, see [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html#51728731) in the documentation for `EvaluationMonitor`, and compare your results with `Plot[Evaluate[f[a]], ...]`.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it is a duplicated question. This one also helps: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87814/97939