# Function inside LogPlot has random offset when using custom working precision

Tags: plotting

I am seeing a strange behavior when using a custom working precision in a `LogPlot` or `LogLogPlot`. Let's take the most simple example of plotting `x` for `x` in `[0.1,1]`.

1. `LogLogPlot` with default working precision gives the correct result

   ```
   LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0.1, 1}]
   ```

[image: LogLogPlotDefaultWP]

2. `Plot` with WorkingPrecision=60 gives the correct result

   ```
   Plot[x, {x, 0.1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
   ```

[image: PlotWP60]

3. `LogLogPlot` with WorkingPrecision=60 gives a wrong artificial offset of 1

   ```
   LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0.1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
   ```

[image: LogLogPlotWP60]

4. If I add `+n` to the function (i.e., plotting `x+n`, the offset increases to `e^n`:

   ```
   LogLogPlot[x + Log[100], {x, 0.1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
   ```

[image: LogLogPlotCustomOffset]

Is this a known behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: known bug : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15628/2079

Comment: Since version 7.0? Can't be so difficult to fix.. Thanks anyways