# Unexpected behaviour of LogLogPlot function

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

I've just installed version 11 of Mathematica and have encountered a bug (which a colleague has reported to WRI). It relates to the seemingly incorrect evaluation of arguments to (at least) the LogLogPlot command.

The following code:

```
y = 10^(-11) x^2.9;
LogLogPlot[y, {x, 1, 10}]
```

does not produce a straight line on the graph but rather a curve, viz:

[image: Erroneous LogLog curve plot]

The above should appear as a straight line as it is a power curve. If you add an `Evaluate` around `y` it will produce the correct straight line, i.e.

[image: Correct plot]

The correct plot will also be produced by any of these commands:

```
f[x_, {a_, b_}] := a x^b
LogLogPlot[f[x, {10^(-11), 2.9}], {x, 1, 10}]
```

and

```
y = 10^(-11) x^2.9
LogLogPlot[y /. x -> z, {z, 1, 10}]
```

So here are the questions:

1. Has anyone else observed these behaviours?
2. Are they in fact bugs or are they some subtle (counterintuitive?) behaviour of Mathematica that I and none of my colleagues who use Mathematica are aware of?

Note once more, this behaviour has been reported to WRI so please don't ask.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me so I added the tag.  But at least [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/logplot-axes-labels-destroyed-when-working-in-high-precision/15642#15642) was fixed in version 11.

Comment: Simple workaround is `LogLogPlot[Evaluate[y], ...]`

Comment: Can you separate these two unrelated problems into two posts?  I am going to remove the observations about `Table`.  Please create a new post for those.

Comment: @Szabolcs, (1) it is a new bug in version 11 and (2) I noted that evaluate is a valid workaround. Thanks for adding the bug label.

Comment: N.B. since you've mentioned that you've made WRI aware of this behavior in the body, there's no need to put it in the title. Also: the `Table[]` stuff and `LogLogPlot[]` stuff seem to me disjoint topics; might be a good idea to split.

Comment: It's really weird.  If I try `u = x^2;`, `LogLogPlot[u, {x, 1, 10}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{x, y}],  MaxRecursion -> 0]`, it appears that `y` actually evaluates to 5.3 when `x=10`!  Even though its definition is still `x^2`.  I really don't understand what is happening.

Comment: 5.3 is actually `Log[10]^2`.  This way `x` appears to evaluate in a different manner: `f[] := {x, y}`, `LogLogPlot[u, {x, 1, 10}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[f[]], MaxRecursion -> 0]`.  We see that `x` gets assigned scaled values.

Comment: I tried to understand in what way this fails and wrote an answer.  If you want, you can send a link to this thread to Wolfram Support (although they might tell you that they don't look at outside links ... I still think its helpful).  Can you please create a second post for the Table issue?

Comment: @Bruce Can you please post your observations about Table as a separate question?

Comment: I can but WRI responded to my colleague stating it is not a bug. Though I tend to disagree. I'll post it tomorrow Australian time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the just released Mathematica 11.0.1.

[image]

Comment: How is buy an upgrade an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 11):

I think this is a bug.  This is just a long comment on what I think is happening here.

First of all, `LogPlot`, `LogLogPlot`, etc. have indeed changed significantly in version 11. [This long standing bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/logplot-axes-labels-destroyed-when-working-in-high-precision/15642#15642) is fixed now.  `Plot` now has the `ScalingFunctions` option, and `Plot[..., ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]` appears to behave exactly the same as `LogLogPlot`, including this bug.

#### What is happening?

Normally `Plot[expr, {x,...}]` behaves by temporarily setting a value to `x` (like [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html)), and then evaluating `expr`.  It seems that this is not true anymore in version 11.  Now we have a mix of setting a value to `x` (`Block`) and *replacing* `x` (`Replace`).

When running

```
u = x^2;
LogLogPlot[u, {x, 1, 10}]
```

the replacement step fails as `u` does not explicitly contain `x`.  However, when `u` is later evaluated, then the temporarily set `OwnValue` of `x` is picked up.

#### What evidence do I have for this?

We can use [`EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) to test what is happening.  But we must do so carefully because it turns out that the replacement step is done on the contents of the `EvaluationMonitor` option as well.

**Test 1:**

```
LogLogPlot[u, {x, 1, 10}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[Hold[x]], 
 MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

This prints `Hold[Exp[x]]`.  This is evidence for the replacement.

**Test 2:**

```
f[] := OwnValues[x]
LogLogPlot[u, {x, 1, 10}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[f[]], 
 MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

This prints from `{HoldPattern[x]:>4.69915*10^-8}` to `{HoldPattern[x]:>2.30259}`, which are `Log[1]` to `Log[10]`.  This is evidence for setting a temporary `OwnValue` for `x`.  I used `f[]` to prevent the replacement.

**Test 3:**

We can see the combined effect of these like so:

```
LogLogPlot[u, {x, 1, 10}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[x], 
 MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

This prints values from `1` to `10`.  This is achieved by first *replacing* `x` by `Exp[x]`, then evaluating it with values from `x=1` to `x=10`.

**Test 4:**

Thus

```
u = x^2;
LogLogPlot[u, {x, 1, 10}]
```

is really equivalent to

```
LogLogPlot[Log[x]^2, {x, 1, 10}]
```

since `x` is really set values not from `1` to `10` but from `Log[1]` to `Log[10]`.

Evaluating these two commands gives the same plot.

---

#### Is this a bug?

My personal opinion is that this is confusing enough that I would call it a bug.  However, I do expect that some will disagree.  Generally, masking the variable of an expression in `Plot` can lead to strange effect in various ways.

The following is a clearer and less error prone way to do the same thing:

```
Clear[u]
u[x_] := x^2
LogLogPlot[u[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks. It will take me a while to digest this but I'm sure my more experienced Mathematica using colleagues will find it immediately useful.

Comment: @BruceCrawford Sorry, I don't think I can say anything *useful* other than what you already said (use `Evaluate`).  I was just trying to shed some light on how things go wrong.  A bug is just a bug ... there's not much we can do other than look for workarounds.