# MMA 11 LogLogPlot issue

Tags: plotting

There are some issues about the 11th version of MMA and this is a very strange one. 
For simplicity I use a simplified function:

```
y=x/(x^2+1)
LogLogPlot[y,{x,10^-7,1}]
```

It doesn't produce any results while this code works:

```
LogLogPlot[x/(x^2+1),{x,10^-7,1}]
```

I hope someone could help.

Comment: Use `Evaluate` on your first example's first argument. This is a known behaviour of the `Plot` family, as it has attribute `HoldAll`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I wrote my code on MMA 10 and it worked always. I tried my code today using 11 and nothing worked. Is this normal?

Comment: According to the docs, `LogLogPlot` was updated in v11, though only `Callout` functions are highlighted. I doubt that it didn't have a hold attribute before... Do you still have v10 to check it again? Plus, you should incorporate this discrepancy between v10 and v11 in your question before it gets closed.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I don't but I am planning to change back to v10 because I have a lot of code written and I cannot afford to change them all by hand. I will let you know asap.

Comment: If it did work in v10, I would say that it is not how it should have been, and v10 had a bug in `LogLogPlot` that was corrected in v11. This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Er... I didn't expect this was actually a correction instead of a bug. Anyway, I also encountered several crashes of v11 which never happened in v10. So I am changing back.

Comment: @Szabolcs It looks similar but you could at least produce something(some curve). In my case there was nothing produced. :-)

Comment: It is the same route cause as [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123943/52) even though the output is slightly different, so yes a duplicate.